# Estimate a Mean using Monte Carlo Integration

Tags: monte-carlo, kernel-smoothing, kullback-leibler

Suppose $\hat f(x)$ is the KDE $$\hat f(x) = \frac{1}{nh}\sum_{i=1}^nK\left(\frac{x - X_i}{h}\right).$$ Now I want to estimate the KL divergence to the true density $f$ using an MC approach:
$$KL = \mathit E\left[\log\left(\frac{f(X)}{\hat f(X)}\right)\right]\approx\frac{1}{m}\sum_{j=1}^m \log\left(\frac{f(x_j)}{\hat f(x_j)}\right),$$ where $x_1, x_2, \dots, x_m$ is an iid sample drawn from $f$.
So far so clear. But $\hat f$ depends on $n$ $X_i$'s. How do I implement that fact? Draw for every $x_i$ another $n$ samples which are then used in the construction of $\hat f$?

Comment: By definition, *any* statistic based on the data "depends on $n$ $X_i$'s." This characterization therefore doesn't distinguish your problem from any other statistical estimation problem.  What, then, do you mean by "implement that fact"??

Comment: Well, if I add the dependency on the sample in the notation, I get $$E\log\frac{f(X)}{\hat f(X; X_1, X_2, \dots, X_n)}\approx m^{-1}\sum_{j=1}^m\log\frac{f(x_j)}{\hat f(x_j; ???)}$$ with that would I need to replace the "???". This is basically my question

Comment: This notation makes little sense.  The "$X$" on the left side must refer to the *variable* $x,$ which is the argument of the function.  The KL divergence is computed by integrating over it, *so $x$ isn't even involved in the meaning of $KL.$*  Your estimate of $KL$ in the question seems pointless: why do you average over the locations of the data in order to compute the KL divergence between the KDE and $f$?  Why aren't you numerically computing $KL(\hat f\mid f)$?

Comment: Well, KL between two densities $f$ and $g$ is defined as $\int f(x)\log\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}\:\mathrm dx = E\log\frac{f(X)}{g(X)}$ using https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_the_unconscious_statistician and from what I know about MC integration, i can sample $x_i\sim f$ and approximate $E[X]$ ($X\sim f$) with $m^{-1}\sum_{i=1}^m x_i$. How would I compute $KL(\hat f|f)$ numerically? Thanks for your patience, I feel like I have a fundamental misunderstanding here

Comment: I suggest using another set of $X_i$'s for computing the Monte Carlo approximation, for a given sample used for computing $\hat f$. Otherwise, Monte Carlo error and statistical variability will be confused together.